# There is remaining space in container from wrapped multi line text

Tags: flutter

There is chat app I am creating and there is the first message is 1 line and working great but the last message is multi line and there is space

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: crossAxisAlignment,
  children: [
    Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right:39),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 9),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(19)),
            ),
        child: Wrap(
          alignment: WrapAlignment.end,
          crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Text(
              widget.msg['content'].trim(),
              maxLines: 39,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.79), fontSize: 17),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 7),
              child: Text(
                DateFormat('HH:mm').format(widget.sendTime),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4), fontSize: 12),
              ),
            ),
           
          ],
        )),
  ],
)
```

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbSvc.png)

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao1AA.png)

Comment: the word is long and it can not be fitted there so that's why it is shown in the next line

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: there's nothing wrong with this, there isn't enough space available to fit the word which is why it's been placed in the next line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5882307/omi-shah you can watch expected image